# Why is a MOSFET used in this opamp current measurement circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I want to make a circuit that will measure the current of a red laser and control the voltage and current as it heats up. As the red laser heats up, its current increases and it burns.

I want to set up a current measurement circuit for a red laser.

While doing this, I will use the INA186 integrated circuit. At this stage, I am trying to build a circuit similar to the circuit in the image below.

I will measure the current on the INA186 integrated circuit via the shunt resistor and enter the output of the integrated circuit into the MCU as an ADC value. At the same time, I provide current-voltage control by creating a closed feedback circuit by manipulating the voltage from the buck regulator circuit I have installed in the circuit.

What is the purpose of using the MOSFET at the output of the INA186?

[image]

Comment: Where did that circuit come from?  What did the circuit designer have to say about it?

Comment: This is a circuit I found on Google Images while researching how to measure the current of the sensor. On the site where I found the image, there was no explanation as to why he put the MOSFET.

Comment: Please attribute the site by adding a reference link into your question. Please also add data sheet links for relevant semiconductors (into your question and not in comments). It does appear that the original author knows little about the INA186.

Comment: The schematic looks like it is from Analog Devices (looks like their style). But the `INA186` text was pasted over the actual IC name. This pinout makes no sense for the INA186.

Comment: Friends, since the internal structure of the INA186 integrated circuit is an opamp, I wrote the current measurement circuit with the shunt resistor that I wanted to install from the internet.
I'm waiting for you to suggest a solution for me.

Comment: No, the INA186 is not an op-amp.

Comment: I added this image to visually explain what I want to do and the circuit I want to build. My question to you is, why was MOSFET used in this current measurement circuit?

Comment: I said INA186 is not an opamp, it has an opamp inside.

Comment: I explained the point of the MOSFET in the original circuit in my answer. But this circuit is not gonna work if you (somehow) "force in" an instrumentation amp instead of the op-amp. If you want to use the INA186 to sense a current, then say so. It even contains application examples for this. But then you cannot use a circuit that was made to sense currents using an op-amp.

Comment: Since I will use the INA186 integrated circuit to read current, I specified it that way in the image. Frankly, I didn't expect you to focus on what I really wanted to ask and worry about whether it is an opamp or not. I also researched current reading applications with the INA186 integrated circuit, but I could not find enough resources. I saw that MOSFETs are generally used at the end of current reading circuits and I asked you why. It's that simple.

Comment: @PID Just be  aware that this circuit *will not work* if you try to use an INA186 in it.

Comment: why did you say that?

Comment: @PID - Hi, (a) You said: "*This is a circuit I found on Google Images*". Every image in a Google Images search result includes a link back to the source webpage. In order to comply with the Stack Exchange [rule for referencing](/help/referencing), which applies to material copied or adapted from elsewhere, we need you to [edit] your question & add a link to that source webpage for the schematic (or the original version, if you modified it). (b) Please see the main site rules in the [tour] & [help] as they differ from typical forums. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The schematic was manipulated (`INA186` was pasted in place of the original IC name) and it doesn't make any sense now, as the INA186 doesn't really correspond to the drawn schematic.

Let's assume that the IC is just an op-amp. The current through RGAIN will be 1/500th of the sensed current through RSENSE. The output PMOS and ROUT convert this current into a ground-referenced sensed voltage again.

$$V_\text{OUT} = I_\text{SENSE}\cdot 10\ \Omega$$